# Get MR source branch on Push event Gitlab Webhook

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to get the merge request (particularly the source branch) that caused a particular Push event on the Gitlab Webhook? I want to run a build only once an MR has been merged (hence the push event), but I want to do slightly different things in my Jenkins build based off of the source branch in the MR. Is this doable using a Push event?

I figure one way to do this manually would be to scrape the commit messages from the push event, and parse out any MR commit messages. However, that seems like a very brittle solution.

If it is not doable, could I use the Accepted MR event instead? And if so, is the Accepted event run after the merge happens? Or would I have to do the Merge myself within the job?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Push Events Webhooks Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events), push events body contains `ref` field, which is actually the branch to which the push has been performed, i.e the source branch of a merge request (if one has been created for this branch).

If you need more detailed information about the merge request, you may find it useful to consider [Merge Requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests). It flexible enough to filter merge requests by `source_branch`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference (and in addition to @Igor)

1. Get the value from the `ref` property
2. Remove the first part of the value `refs/heads/`
3. Get the value from the `project_id` property
4. Search with the merge requests via the API (Note this can be more than one!) via:

GET :: `projects/' + project_id + '/merge_requests?source_branch=' + s_ref + '&per_page=100&page=' + i_page`

Make sure that s_ref  is url encoded.